# Making simple rnn code with scan function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I recently started to learn Tensorflow and try to make simple rnn code using scan function.
What I'm trying to do is to make The RNN predict sine function.
It gets input of 1 dim. and outputs also 1 dim in batch as follow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials import mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import time

# FLAGS (options)
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "", "")
#tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("read_attn", True, "enable attention for reader")
#tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("write_attn",True, "enable attention for writer")
opt = tf.flags.FLAGS

#Parameters
time_step = 10
num_rnn_h = 16
batch_size = 2
max_epoch=10000
learning_rate=1e-3 # learning rate for optimizer
eps=1e-8 # epsilon for numerical stability

#temporary sinusoid data
x_tr = np.zeros([batch_size,time_step])
y_tr = np.zeros([batch_size,time_step])
ptrn = 0.7*np.sin(np.arange(time_step+1)/(2*np.pi))
x_tr[0] = ptrn[0:time_step]
y_tr[0] = ptrn[1:time_step+1]
x_tr[1] = ptrn[0:time_step]
y_tr[1] = ptrn[1:time_step+1]

#Build model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[batch_size,time_step,1], name= 'input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,time_step,1], name= 'target')
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_rnn_h)
#cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_h, state_is_tuple=True)
with tf.variable_scope('output'):
    W_o = tf.get_variable('W_o', shape=[num_rnn_h, 1])
    b_o = tf.get_variable('b_o', shape=[1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

#make graph
#rnn_outputs, final_states = tf.scan(cell, xx1, initializer= tf.zeros([num_rnn_h]))
scan_outputs = tf.scan(lambda a, xi: cell(xi, a), tf.transpose(x, perm=[1,0,2]), initializer= init_state)
rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(scan_outputs,perm=[1,2,0,3]))
print rnn_outputs, rnn_states

with tf.variable_scope('predictions'):
    weighted_sum = tf.reshape(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, num_rnn_h]), W_o), [batch_size, time_step, 1])
    predictions = tf.add(weighted_sum, b_o, name='predictions')
with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((y - predictions) ** 2, name='loss')

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

But It gives an error at the last line (optimizer) like ,

> ValueError: Shapes (2, 16) and (2, 2, 16) are not compatible

Please someone knows the reason, tell me how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your error is not on the last line (the optimizer) but rather on some operation you are doing earlier. Perhaps in the reduce_mean with this y - prediction? I will not go over your code in details but I will tell you that this error comes when you do an operation between two tensors which require the same shape (usually math operations).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michel. I though it was on the last line because the error message occurred in the line. Then I need to check other lines also. Another question is, if the shape is not matched in another line, why error is not shown in that line? Is it possible to make a computational graph in the beginning?

Comment: Without the last line, it runs. It means the error might occur while it compute gradient(I guess inside scan function...). How should I debug this?

Comment: When I have shape issues to debug in tensorflow I find it helpful to print out the shape of every tensor (you can use get_shape) to see where they aren't lining up.

Comment: Printing the shape is usually helpful. Also, you can easily print some summaries and use Tensorboard, it`s the best tool for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As you guys recommended, I printed shape of the tensors and everythings seems matching. And also checked the Tensorboard. What I found was those (2,16) or (2,2,16) size tensors are shown inside the while loop in the scan function. And if I replace scan_outputs with dummy variable with same size, it runs. So the error happens inside the scan. But how can I fix it? Is it because I use the scan function wrongly?? But it looks okay if I understand it correctly(maybe not...)

Comment: Actually, I found that the shape of initializer and input/output to the rnn_cell was not matching. Thank you for the all comments!